# Create a Large Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, out-of-memory

I am trying to create a symmetrical numpy array with values ranging between 0.4- 1 with 20000*20000 rows and columns. However, I am getting a memory error when I create this big array.
 Please find my code below.

import numpy as np

```
def random_symmetric_matrix(n):
    _R = np.random.uniform(0.4,1,n*(n-1)/2)
    P = np.zeros((n,n))
    P[np.triu_indices(n, 1)] = _R
    P[np.tril_indices(n, -1)] = P.T[np.tril_indices(n, -1)]
    print P
    np.savetxt("b.txt",P, delimiter=' ')
    return P

random_symmetric_matrix(6000)
```

Comment: Where's the traceback?

Comment: @hpaulj: Memory Error

Comment: An array consisting of (20000*20000)/2 floating point numbers *is* actually a really large object, on the order of gigabytes

Comment: @RojanKarakaya: Yeah, do we have a way of creating it?

Comment: How large is your RAM-memory?

Comment: @RojanKarakaya: 16 Gigs

Comment: I asked for traceback.  You already gave use the error.  We need to know where it occurred.  If it was in the `np.zeros` you are clearly making something too big.  Later in code we might find ways around it.

Comment: Which OS? If Linux try `ulimit -s unlimited`.

Comment: look into using pytables as storage, [this](https://kastnerkyle.github.io/posts/using-pytables-for-larger-than-ram-data-processing/) is really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your function, and removed the print and savetxt:

```
In [574]: def random_symmetric_matrix(n):
     ...:     _R = np.random.uniform(0.4,1,n*(n-1)//2)
     ...:     P = np.zeros((n,n))
     ...:     print('...')
     ...:     P[np.triu_indices(n, 1)] = _R
     ...:     print(',,,')
     ...:     P[np.tril_indices(n, -1)] = P.T[np.tril_indices(n, -1)]
     ...:     return P
```

On an old small machine it start to bog down with n=4000.

Here's my first memory error:

```
In [573]: random_symmetric_matrix(14000).shape
...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-573-32a007267a79> in <module>()
----> 1 random_symmetric_matrix(14000).shape

<ipython-input-565-9f171b601d49> in random_symmetric_matrix(n)
      3     P = np.zeros((n,n))
      4     print('...')
----> 5     P[np.triu_indices(n, 1)] = _R
      6     print(',,,')
      7     P[np.tril_indices(n, -1)] = P.T[np.tril_indices(n, -1)]

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py in triu_indices(n, k, m)
    973 
    974     """
--> 975     return where(~tri(n, m, k=k-1, dtype=bool))
    976 
    977 

MemoryError:
```

Focusing on the problem statement:

```
In [576]: np.triu_indices(4,1)
Out[576]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int32))
In [577]: np.triu_indices(4,1)[0].shape
Out[577]: (6,)
In [578]: np.triu_indices(400,1)[0].shape
Out[578]: (79800,)
In [579]: np.triu_indices(4000,1)[0].shape
Out[579]: (7998000,)
```

It doesn't have problems constructing `tri`; but collecting the `where` indices blows the memory.

```
In [593]: T=np.tri(10000, 10000, k=-1, dtype=bool)
In [594]: T.shape
Out[594]: (10000, 10000)
In [595]: np.where(T)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-595-33094d2967ea> in <module>()
----> 1 np.where(T)

MemoryError:
```

So while it appears to have enough memory for the `P` array, indexing along the way uses up too much memory.  Of hand I don't know of a way around this, but at least we now know where to search.

Comment: If there's no sufficient memory then it has to be done the traditional way, loop (perhaps by chunks for a little speed up) and set the indexes.